# What's could it be wrong in this Linux Assembler Code?

Tags: linux, assembly, x86

I need to make a simple 4 functions calculator for 2 numbers coding with Linux Assembler, however the programm works not fully ok because sometimes fails on reading the 2 numbers.

My setup and data:

```
bits 32
global main

extern scanf
extern printf
extern exit

section .data
    menu:   db ; truncated, but essentially a string            
    msg1:   db "El resultado de la suma es: %d", 10, 0
    msg2:   db "El resultado de la resta es: %d", 10, 0
    msg3:   db "El resultado de la multiplicacion es: %d", 10, 0
    msg4:   db "El resultado de la division es: %d", 10, 0
    in1:    db "Proporciona dato 1: ", 10
    in2:    db "Proporciona dato 2: ", 10   
    fmt:    db "%d"
    x:      dd 0
    y:      dd 0
```

The function I believe isn't always working:

```
leer:
    push dword in1
    call printf
    add esp, 4

    push dword x
    push dword fmt
    call scanf
    add esp, 8

    push dword in2
    call printf
    add esp, 4

    push dword y
    push dword fmt
    call scanf
    add esp, 8
    ret
```

The original code can be found here:
http://notepad.cc/piloobru13

Comment: @Diego I've pulled the code I think is relevant onto your question and added some tags. Using paste bins and posting your entire code is frowned upon here, so remember to include the parts you think are relevant. You can format your code with the `{}` button. Also, at the button of your question just underneath the tags, there's an `edit` link, so if you ever need to change anything that's the way to do it. Welcome to Stack Overflow.

Comment: What compiler is this? I don't recognize the syntax, and neither does GNU as

Comment: The program fails how? Error message? Segfault? Incorrect result?

Comment: @sehe: Its intel syntax, which is more readable for people with DOS/Windows background. Try `as -msyntax=intel`

Comment: @Turbo J: mmm... thx, but I still get loads of errors (No such instruction, ambigious operand size, junk after expression). I'll leave it at this because it's probably just me. I used to code with MASM back in the days, but I haven't got it around now

Comment: It's NASM for Linux, 8086 family

Comment: The programms sometimes works ok 5 or 10 times, but suddenly back to the menu, It doesn't read well or if I press any option for an operation it quits

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some of your strings are not zero terminated.

That will likely confuse printf and scanf.

Comment: Do you refer about the in1 and in2 strings?
Somehow if I add 0 it definitely doesn't work

Comment: Yes, and the `fmt` which initially happens to be zero terminated, until you enter new values for x and y.